# Ubuntu 'Failed to import the site module' error message

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I get the following error message below. When I try to run a python file with the command `python3 training.py`

I found a potential solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446220/linux-weird-python-output) but when I went to make the suggested change it appeared that my machine had what was considered the correct setup.

To clarify, I have did significant research and none of the following fixes work

- [GitHub 286](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/286)
- [1192890](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.3/+bug/1192890)
- [1480388](https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+bug/1480388)

Any suggestions to what it could be and how to fix it?

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

Comment: i suggest viewing this page https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/286

Comment: @Ahmad the link above circles back around to the article I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this. I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.x and the issues is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but on windows, so Im not sure if this will help. Turns out I has some environment variables that were causing the terminal to screw it.

I downloaded `anaconda` but had `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONSCRIPTS` as environmental variables. I deleted those since anaconda creates it's own environmental variables for the terminal to use. Problem solved after that.

Note: Be sure to restart after deleting

Comment: I've started using Anaconda to manage my Python installations,hopefully I won't get this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue on windows. I was installing python with PyCharm after I erased other version of python and the program looked for site-packages in the old location. I just installed the pip.exe file by double click from the Scripts folder of new python that I installed.