# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to open Idle for Python 3.8

Tags: python

I tried launching idle on the command prompt by using `python -i -m idlelib`
This the error that occurred:

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()  
  File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site.py", line 567, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)  
  File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site.py", line 350, in addsitepackages      
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)  
  File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site.py", line 208, in addsitedir  
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)  
  File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site.py", line 164, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):  
  File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]  
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 654: character maps to undefined
```

Comment: @superb rain My bad it was a typo, I did try `idlelib`

Comment: Are you actually running Python 3.8? If not, the problem is probably that you hardcoded a `PYTHONPATH` which imports the libraries for 3.8 on all versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try `python -i` first and see if you can access the idle on the console.

Once you've verified that, you should then open idle on your pc and try `import idlelib`. If it doesn't load that means that either you don't have that module or its not in you path (which you can fix by finding its location and running `import sys; sys.path.append("path/to/module")`).

My guess would be that you have multiple versions of python on your pc and when you're running python you are not using the version that has this module.

A person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054297/8280477) seems to have had a similar problem, albeit with a different program where the environmental variables they used caused problems. I recommend getting a package like conda. That'll reduce the likelihood of running into these problems immensely.