# Weird Linux Issue: ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

This is the error I am getting

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

Any thoughts? I have an anaconda distribution, and I am running this off of Jenkins on a google VM I have spinning.

When I try to run python, python3, python3.5 from the shell I get these errors.

Weirdly though I have no issues when I run python2 from the shell, it works fine....

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also having this problem and I can see that you also commented on the accepted answer [on the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446220/linux-weird-python-output) from a while ago. Like you, my ```etc/bash.bashrc``` doesn't have ```python``` in front of the command. I tried adding ```python 3.3``` and ```python 3.5``` in front of it but neither worked. Did you find a fix for the problem?

Comment: No I did not. I ended up reinstalling my conda environments. :/

Comment: Are you using anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems like Anaconda related issue.

Try to run python in ipython notebook or pycharm and select which environment you want to use.

```
jupyter notebook
```

Also if you create conda virtual environment it should allow you to use python as is.

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4
source activate myenv
```

Another soution might be to remove anaconda from the PATH variable